# How to find all date-ranges overlapping another date-range in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

everyone!

I have a record of this type:

```
{
    start: 2015-03-27T15:00:00.000Z,
    end: 2015-03-27T17:00:00.000Z
}
```

and trying to find in the database crossing periods.

```
{
    start: 2015-03-27T15:30:00.000Z,
    end: 2015-03-27T16:00:00.000Z
}
```

I do scheduling system. And I was not there for some time occupied.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly. What exactly is a "crossing period"? Is one of those code snippets your query? Or are both from different documents and you want to find any documents where the date-ranges overlap?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to find documents with overlapping date ranges. In other words any document whose `start` or `end` dates falls in between given date range.

You can definitely achieve this with little bit match and logic.

Let's assume I have two documents in my collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f692730c96eddb0a2c287e"), 
    "start" : "2015-03-27T15:00:00.000Z", 
    "end" : "2015-03-27T17:00:00.000Z"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f6928c0c96eddb0a2c287f"), 
    "start" : "2015-03-27T16:00:00.000Z", 
    "end" : "2015-03-27T27:00:00.000Z"
}
```

When I execute following piece of code

```
var startDate = "2015-03-27T20:00:00.000Z";
var endDate = "2015-03-27T21:00:00.000Z";

var findOverlapingDates = function(startDate, endDate){
  return db.collection.find({
     $or: [
        {$and: [
          {start:{$gte: startDate}}, {start:{$lte: endDate}}
        ]},
        {start:{$lte: startDate}, end:{$gte: startDate}}
     ]
  });
};

printjson(findOverlapingDates(startDate, endDate).toArray());
```

I get

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56f6928c0c96eddb0a2c287f"), 
        "start" : "2015-03-27T16:00:00.000Z", 
        "end" : "2015-03-27T27:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Which is overlapping document for given date range. Hope it all makes sense. For best performance, I'll recommend having index on both `start` and `end` fields.

Comment: It should have been obvious that the reason no-one answered is because that is not what the OP is asking. They just expect to "identify" any "overlap" that occurs in the data. So therefore show that the two records above "overlap" without querying for a specific time range.