# How can I check if date falls between two dates in mongoDB using C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a list stored in MongoDB that contains objects. Each object has a start date and an end date.

When I insert a new object into a list, I check whether it exists in the collection by using his ID.

If the object exists, I want to check that the dates do not overlap...how do i check it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have tried so far but I don't want to outright give you all the code especially since I don't know what you have done.

The.find() query will return all documents a collection and returns all fields from the documents. The documentation is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#examples) In addition to this I would probably use the [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) keyword within MongoDB in order to test the collection.

After the .find query finds the dates and you filter the query then we can use the $lte and $gte to filter through the dates and get them in a certain sequence so we can see which dates are between which range. The [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) and [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) syntax words are hyperlinked for you to check out the documentation.

If this doesn't help I also think this could be a duplicate of the following question:[MongoDB_Possible_Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235504/how-to-find-all-date-ranges-overlapping-another-date-range-in-mongodb)